# How to disable hostname verification in spring webclient?

Tags: java

I am using the spring webflux webclient tool to call the API. The API server address is HTTPS, and it is an IP address without a domain name. I need to disable the hostname validation in webclient. The exception now is as follows

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 180.101.147.89 found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:168) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:461) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

```
@Bean
    public WebClient telcomWebclient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
                                     @Value("${telcom.api.host}") String telcomApiHost,
                                     @Value("${telcom.api.certificate-name}") String telcomApiCertificateName,
                                     @Value("${telcom.api.certificate-store-pass}") String telcomApiCertificateStorePass) {
        try {
            KeyStore selfCert = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            selfCert.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cert/outgoing.CertwithKey.pkcs12"), "IoM@1234".toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("sunx509");
            kmf.init(selfCert, "IoM@1234".toCharArray());

            KeyStore caCert = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
            caCert.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cert/" + telcomApiCertificateName), telcomApiCertificateStorePass.toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("sunx509");
            tmf.init(caCert);

            SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                    .keyManager(kmf)
                    .trustManager(tmf)
                    .build();
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            return webClientBuilder.clientConnector(clientHttpConnector).baseUrl(telcomApiHost).build();
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            log.error("Config webclient,error occurs", e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aside from disabling SSL verification entirely, (**WHICH I DON'T RECOMMEND**) by passing in `InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE` like this:

```java
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                    .keyManager(kmf)
                    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
```

You can configure the HttpClient to essentially override the hostname verification by configuring a custom [SNIMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SNIMatcher.html) as below:

```java
HttpClient.create().create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec
    .sslContext(sslContext)
    .handlerConfigurator(sslHandler -> 
        SSLEngine engine = handler.engine();
        //engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
        List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();

        SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        matchers.add(matcher);
        params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
        engine.setSSLParameters(params);
);
```

I have tested this and verified it worked. I hope this helps!

This was inspired by the answer here: [Configure HostnameVerifier with reactor netty for spring-webflux WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542066/configure-hostnameverifier-with-reactor-netty-for-spring-webflux-webclient)

Comment: Great!Thank you vert much!

Comment: @James It works fine and bypass hostname verification for all in webclient. Do we have any solution if we want to bypass hostname verification only for few host and rest should still verified? similar to X509Hostnameverifier while calling rest template we can add check for what domain we want to bypass.

Answer (score 10):

Actually SNIMatcher is for server side only. This can be verified by putting
a break point on the return of the matches() method. Execution never stops at that break point. 
 The actual reason the host name verification is skipped because the newly params.identificationAlgorithm value is null instead of "HTTPS" when the SSLParameters is overriden.

 Here is a simpler code which works as well as above.

```
           HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec
                   .sslContext(sslContext)
                   .handlerConfigurator(sslHandler -> {
                       SSLEngine engine = handler.engine();
                       SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters(engine.getSSLParameters().getCipherSuites(), engine.getSSLParameters().getProtocols());
                       // With java update null value is no longer sufficient to skip host name verification
                       params.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("");
                       engine.setSSLParameters(params);
                   }));
```

Comment: Works for me, Thanks! Slight simplification.

```java
SSLEngine engine = sslHandler.engine();
SSLParameters params = engine.getSSLParameters();
// With java update null value is no longer sufficient to skip host name verification
params.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("");
engine.setSSLParameters(params);
```

Comment: Lambda param is `sslHandler` but param in block is `handler`, just an fyi.