# Custom Reactor Netty hostname verifier

Tags: java, ssl, netty, reactor-netty

I need to query a third-party API that has a certificate/DNS name mismatch. The left-most label of the hostname specified in the certificate is not known in advance (i.e. *CN=some-random-hash.example.com*) and therefore I want to configure a HTTP client with a custom hostname verifier.

When using the default *Reactor Netty* client obtained via `HttpClient.create()`, a `HostnameChecker` class fails certificate validation and causes an exception to be thrown:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching XXX found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)
    ... 30 more
```

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56430381/3527464) suggests implementing an SNIMatcher as follows:

```
HttpClient.create()
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .handlerConfigurator((handler) -> {
                    SSLEngine engine = handler.engine();
                    SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
                    List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();
                    SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    };
                    matchers.add(matcher);
                    params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
                    engine.setSSLParameters(params);
                }));
```

However, according to the [Javadocs of setSNIMatchers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html#setSNIMatchers(java.util.Collection)):

> This method is only useful to SSLSockets or SSLEngines operating in
>   server mode.

The matcher is consequently being ignored and even worse, the above code creates an empty set of `SSLParameters`, which seems to disable the SSL verification entirely.

How would one properly implement a custom hostname verifier with *Reactor Netty*?

Note that when using the *Apache HTTPClient* library, this can be trivially achieved with the following:

```
HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> ...).build();
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever get to find a workaround?

Comment: No, for now I switched to the Apache HTTPClient library.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing the same. Had to figure out how to integrate the apache http client library with Spring Webclient but it's now finally working. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: same issue.. Any lead ?